# Парсинг JSON. Получить значение полей,независимо от их названия.

Tags: android, json, gson

Делаю конвертер валют. Использую [это](https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/latest?base=USD&symbols=PLN) api.

Получаю ,как видно:

```
{"base":"USD","rates":{"PLN":3.6950587422},"date":"2018-09-28"}
```

Как получить курс,здесь

> 3.6950587422

не создавая  getPLN,а допустим по маске(первый элемент поля номер х,как select в css),так как валюты могут быть разные.

Использую GsonConverter+Retrofit2+RxJava. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: А что такое "первое поле" ? Стандарт json не обещает точного порядка полей. поля в json могут быть в любом порядке. API имеет полное право указать поля например как date, base, rates

Comment: но вы можете из json сделать объект и начать обходить rates например `for( ... in ...)` и прервать цикл после первого поля

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявите `rates` с типом `Map`

```
Map<String, Double> rates;

public Map<String, Double> getRates() {
    return rates;
}
```

Получаем значения:

```
current = pojo.getRates().get("PLN"); // мы ведь знаем что запрашивали PLN
```